# Difference between = and {} in-class initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, in-class-initialization

When I want t put initial values inside the class definition there are two ways it can be done: with {} and =

```
class A
{
public:
   int a = 1;
   bool b = false;
   someClass* obj = nullptr;
};

class B
{
public:
   int a {1};
   bool b {false};
   someClass* obj {nullptr};
};
```

Is there any difference between those two options? Will in class A and B be something different in a way fields where initialized?

With = it will be copy initialization, so with {} should be more efficient? Or in case of in-class initialization they are equal and just provide different syntax?

Comment: There are some nuanced differences.  If you have an hour to kill, here's a fairly comprehensive presentation that covers those differences [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis at CppCon 2018.  For instance, change both `1` to `1.0` and see the difference in what the compiler does.  (I don't remember all the nuances off the top of my head, otherwise I'd take a stab at answering.)  You might want the `language-lawyer` tag, if you want chapter-and-verse... but it's a simple question with a BIG answer.

Comment: There may be more or better duplicate targets - feel free to edit the list (if you have a hammer) or ping me with suggestions (if you don't).